# Deploying Ruby/Python backend services in WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have written several webservices in Python and Ruby and would like to integrate them with WSO2 Integration Studio. I tried following the instructions on the docs about sending messages to services [here](https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/85376682) but it's about Java microservices only. Am I supposed to deploy my services elsewhere and only use http endpoints to integrate them? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only copy JAR files to the /wso2/msf4j/deployment/microservices folder and deploy them in the MSF4J profile of WSO2 EI.

> Am I supposed to deploy my services elsewhere and only use http endpoints to integrate them?

Yes, This is the way to achieve this.